# What's the difference between the operation Ctrl+Shift+F and the operation double Shift in PyCharm?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

It's said that the operation `double-shift` can search just as `Ctrl+Shift+F` does. But why I can't find the file destination with the same string by using `double-shift`? If it's my problem, how can I find my file destination by using `double-shift`?

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

I'm using PyCharm community edition 2020.1 on windows 10 64bit.

[image: using double Shift can't find my goal file]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double `Shift` is *Search Everywhere*, where you can search also outside your project, or in the help, or for actions.

`Control-Shift-F` is *Find in Path*, is a more classic find, but on all files (depending the file filter).

Comment: But why I  can't find the file which I can find with `Control-Shift-F`  by `Double-Shift`?

Comment: They are different. If you want to look for the string "app.make_response", use *Find in Path*. As you see in the "search", if will not find a string (there is not such string in the files). if you look near `All`, you find what `All` means: classes, symbols, actions, files (so not string, but it use a context aware database, and for *symbols* and *classes* we mean the definitions or the declaration, not the calling/use [but I know this, because I come from C language, it may not be evident for most of programmers]).

Answer (score 0):

Double `shift` navigate to the following destinations:
types, symbols, files, recent files, actions, tool windows, run configurations, preferences, Git branches, commits, tags, messages, and so on.

Note that this command is not a replacement for **textual search** — use `Shift+F` to search text in the current document, and `Control+Shift+F` to search text in the entire solution.

Source: [JetBrains-Manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Searching_Everywhere.html#start-the-search)